# Computation the fundamental group in two complex variables

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\Delta$ be the unit disk in the complex plane and $0<\epsilon <<1$.
My purpose is to compute the fundamental group of the following.
$X :=\{ (z,w)\in \Delta \times \Delta \; | \; zw\neq \epsilon   \}$.
This is the complementary of the analytic hypersurface $\{ zw=\epsilon \}$ in $\Delta^2$.

I used Van Kampen's Theorem by using the following method:

$z=re^{i\alpha}$ and $w=se^{i\beta}$.
Then $zw \in X $ if and only if $rs \neq \epsilon$ or $\alpha + \beta \neq 0 [2\pi]$.

It follows that

$X= X_1 \cup X_2$
where 
$X_1= \{  rs < \epsilon \; or \;  \alpha + \beta \neq 0 [2\pi] \}$
and $X_2= \{  rs > \epsilon \; or \;  \alpha + \beta \neq 0 [2\pi] \}  $.

Is this the good way to solve my problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your curve is a small perturbation of $\{zw=0\}$. The complement of the latter is $(\Delta\smallsetminus0)^2$, and its group $\Bbb Z^2$ is abelian. By Zariski's theorem, a small perturbation results in a quotient of $\pi_1$; hence, the group in question is also abelian, hence equals $H_1$, hence is $\Bbb Z$. (Poincare duality and such.) Of course, this particular group is just **known** to be $\Bbb Z$; what's written above is merely a brief explanation.

Comment: Zariski proved a lot of theorems, which one is this?

Comment: As stated: perturbing a reduced algebraic curve changes $\pi_1$ to a quotient. As far as I remember, it's "On the problem of existence of functions...". Of course, there, the setting is slightly different (projective plane curves), but the approach and the prove extend to the case in question (and would commonly be referred to as Zariski--van Kampen theorem/method/...)